# Get a template parse error when running tests for Angular2

Tags: angular, gulp, webpack-2

Folks,

I'm having a problem running my unit tests for Angular2 (I use a gulp task for this), however I get the following error when I try:

```
Failed: Template parse errors:
        Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li routerLinkActive="active">
                  <a [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['signup']">Sign Up</a>
                  <a [routerLink]="['login']">Login</a>
                </li>"): HeaderComponent@15:13
```

When I remove the references to `routerLink` from the HTML template everything works fine. Following is the definition of my webpack.test.js file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders:
          [
            'awesome-typescript-loader',
            'angular2-template-loader'
          ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader'

      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: [ 'raw-loader', 'sass-loader' ]
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
      /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
      helpers.root('./client/src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    )
  ]
};
```

This is the test that I'm trying to run:

```
describe("HeaderComponent", () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [HeaderComponent],
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it('should display a form to register', () => {
    let navbar = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('navbar'));
    console.log(navbar);
    expect(navbar).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Anyone have any ideas what I'm missing? My normal `webpack.dev.js` works without any issue. It's something specific to my testing setup. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I tried removing `angular2-template-loader` too, but got a different error about not being able to find the template - which makes sense at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not including the RouterModule and necessary providers in your test setup:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([], {useHash: false})
  ],
  declarations: [ ComponentUnderTest ],
  providers: [
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }
  ]
})
```

Comment: I've updated my question with the test itself. I'm absolutely **not** adding it to the imports of the test itself. I was getting too caught up in thinking it was a template problem. Ugh.

Comment: Yeah definitely ran into this one as well when I first started getting into unit testing with Angular. Don't forget to include both the imports and the provider as I've shown here. Please feel free to upvote and accept if this fixes your problem

Comment: I tried using `RouterModule`, but it threw an exception `Bootstrap at least one component before injecting Router.`, replaced `RouterModule` with `RouterTestingModule` and everything worked like a charm. Thanks for the heads up on the imports @jesse-carter it set me in the right direction - I'll mark this as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your declaring/provisioning of the routing set up in your tests?  Without those, the parser will not be able to understand the directive.